# Display a table in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, formatting

I am trying to display a table with two columns and 86 rows. Instead of outputting the rows, the size is stated. Is there a way to change this? I am new to MATLAB and am coming from a background in C/C++ so I may just be approaching this all wrong. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
angle = 0:a(as);
    time_available = y;
    T = table(angle, time_available)
```

and here is the output:

```
     angle        time_available
 _____________    ______________

 [1x86 double]    [1x86 double]
```

Comment: can you provide the y and a variables.

Comment: angle = 0:1:85, and y is an array of polyvals between 0 and 3e6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have to transpose them.

```
clc
clear

angle = (0:1:85)';
polyvals = ((1:86).^2)';
T = table(angle, polyvals)
```

gives

```
T = 

    angle    polyvals
    _____    ________

     0          1    
     1          4    
     2          9    
     3         16    
     4         25    
     5         36    
     6         49    
     7         64
```

Comment: corrected the inputs of table so that each column shows the name.

Comment: Idk why it makes a difference, but it didn't work exactly how you wrote it, however transposing it within T worked:
    T = table(angle', time_available')     Thank you!

Comment: As it is shown in my answer, you have to transpose them before you can input them into the `table` function.

Comment: It worked when I just transposed the array within the table. Is there a reason that it is better to transpose before putting it into the table?

Comment: Oh, it just displays the titles of the columns as var1 and var2 when transposing within the table. Never mind. Thanks again!